# fill text and search on web by selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web, webdriver, web-crawler, autofill

I would like to fill text and then enter to search some keywords in this website.
i tried myself some ways but did not run,
so please help me!
Thanks you so much!
https://shopee.vn/
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the text in the search box via below way, I used `python` to do it not sure about you as there is no `code` given by you, but the way remain the same.

```
driver.get("https://shopee.vn/")

search_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shopee-searchbar-input__input")
search_box.send_keys("iphone")

search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

***import***

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

It will be good, if you post some code, in case the above solution does not work for you.

Comment: thanks you, it worked for me.
but it tried to click on button (<div class="shopee-sort-by-options__option">Bán chạy</div>), but it also does not run,
code as:
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]").click()

Comment: i also tried but not run, ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
''
driver.find_element_by_class_name("shopee-sort-by-options__option").click()

Comment: This seems to be another locator you wanted to click, it would be good if you add the new post for this, as above is solved.